# gridview rotate screen overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, datagridview

im having a issue where everytime my phone rotates, the column will show a render overflow, i've tried adding a scrollview already...

Image here ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0IuE.jpg

```
class AccountTabGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      child: GridView.count(
        primary: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/images/orders.png'),
                  Text(
                    'Order History',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap column children with Expanded !

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope it will work

```
   SliverGrid(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        childAspectRatio: 4.0,
      ),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
             Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('assets/images/orders.png'),
                  Text(
                    'Order History',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 20,
      ),
    ),
```

more information to visit  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html